# javascript reflection: get variables

Tags: javascript, reflection, variables

how can be a collection of global and/or local varibles be obtained in javascript?

(like e.g. in Python by `globals()` or `locals()`)

if there is no such functionality available in javascript, how do some javascript console interfaces obtain them, to be able to autocomplete?

Comment: here i have found pretty similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831932/access-all-local-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `for` / `in` loop.

To get all globals:

```
for(var name in this) {
    var value = this[name];
    //Do things
}
```

(This will only work correctly when run in global scope; you can wrap it in an anonymous function to ensure that.  However, beware of `with` blocks)

To get all properties of a particular object:

```
for(var name in obj) {
    //Optionally:
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;    //Skip inherited properties

    var value = obj[name];
    //Do things
}
```

However, there is no way to loop through all *local* variables.

Comment: well, this is an object in(tro)spection, not exactly what i am asking for. but definitely useful for browser environment reflection.

Comment: Then what are you asking for?

Comment: SLaks: you note that it's not possible would be sufficient, if it's the case (it was not already there in time of writing my previuos comment)

Comment: SLaks: .. my answer was meant rather on pure javascript, where is no `window` object. but your answer this is useful for browser env, thanks :)

Comment: If there is no `window`, you can use `this` in global scope.

Comment: i'm afrad `this` would interfere with jQuery behavior

Comment: You can't iterate with `for..in` over the global scope in JScript (IE) can you?

Comment: SLaks: unfortunately, `this` seems to be redefined by jQuery's event mechanism, so such an introspection, using `this` does not work inside user-bound jQuery's event functions. but it's a different problem..

Comment: @mykhal: You can save a reference to the global `this` elsewhere, or you can put the loop in a separate function.