# Return value after eval

Tags: javascript, function, eval, return

```
function someFunc() { return 'Hello, world'; }
function call(funcName) { eval(funcName + '()'); }

console.log(call('someFunc'));
```

But `console.log` doesn't print 'Hello world'. How can I return value after `eval` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
call(funcName) { window[funcName](); }
```

And don't use the `void` keyword. It ignores return values and always returns undefined from a statement.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but if eval works in with clousures (like functions in functions etc), than that code won't work.

Comment: @Alxandr depends where the call function is defined. Depends where `someFunc` is defined. It's bad to rely on that. You really want to store functions on an object and call them by string key on the object.

Comment: @Raynos how about something like `(this[fnName] || window[fnName])()`?

Comment: However, what if I did `function a() { var b = function() {/*do something*/}; call('b'); }` (silly example, yes I know). Not that it has anything to do with OP, but I'm just curious :-P

Comment: @Alxandr `b` is defined as a local variable on the stack. It is not accesible in `this` not in the global scope (`window`). `b`lives in the CallObject. [You can't programmatically access it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831932/access-all-local-variables)

Comment: @Raynos what would `eval('b')` yield when called inside a then? I've tried this in FF now, and it gives me the function b, thought it might differ between browsers. So, how about something like `function call(name) { var f = eval(name); if(typeof name == 'function') { f(); }}`. Then you just need to do some sort of regex to check that name isn't malicious js. A bit overkill maybe, but that use of eval I wouldn't call evil, no?

Comment: @Alxandr alternatively don't write shit generic code that requires the use of `eval`. Sorry but eval should be avoided for most cases. It's uses are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question using eval :

```
function someFunc() { return 'Hello, world'; }

function call(funcName) { return eval(funcName + '()'); }

console.log(call('someFunc'));
```

And you can use eval if you trust the input. this is the rule of thumb

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval` -- it's evil. Why don't you try this:

[Get JavaScript function-object from its name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/773184/50079)

After getting a reference to the function, you can simply call it and use the return value directly.